# Why does this XSLT add content after the template is complete?

Tags: xml, xslt

So the bigger picture is that I'm trying to determine why there's "content in prolog" (which is not allowed).

It looks like the content that's being included is coming from the result of this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!-- <xsl:template match="props['xpath_matchHoursDateType']">  -->
    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry[1]/wd:Employee_ID">
        <Root>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </Root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...which, when applied to the following XML, produces a result that I find surprising:

```
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Employee_ID>123456</wd:Employee_ID>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Employee_ID>234567</wd:Employee_ID>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Employee_ID>345678</wd:Employee_ID>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Employee_ID>456789</wd:Employee_ID>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:RBO_Group>
            <wd:Date_Worked>12/15/2014</wd:Date_Worked>
            <wd:Hours>41.53</wd:Hours>
            <wd:Type>TypeA</wd:Type>
            <wd:Process_Date>09/20/2019</wd:Process_Date>
        </wd:RBO_Group>
        <wd:RBO_Group>
            <wd:Date_Worked>12/15/2014</wd:Date_Worked>
            <wd:Hours>41.53</wd:Hours>
            <wd:Type>TypeA</wd:Type>
            <wd:Process_Date>01/30/2020</wd:Process_Date>
        </wd:RBO_Group>
        <wd:Employee_ID>567890</wd:Employee_ID>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

The result being:

```
<Root xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"><wd:Employee_ID>123456</wd:Employee_ID></Root>23456734567845678912/15/201441.53TypeA09/20/201912/15/201441.53TypeA01/30/2020567890
```

My expectation is that the template would match the "wd:Employee_ID" node of the first "wd:Report_Entry" node it finds, copy it, and then be done. So I'm surprised to see anything after the closing Root tag. I'm not the best XSL programmer, and I'm just now working with streamable XSL 3.0, so that might be part of the equation.

I'm passing this XML result along to another XSL transform, which SEEMS to be complaining about content being included in the prolog, which I can only imagine is this extra content after the root closes.

**So, why is the rest of the XML content being added to the result after the template is (AFAIK) complete?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every XSLT stylesheet contains what's called "default rules". These will recursively process the input document in the following fashion, starting from the root node:

1. find child nodes, apply templates to them
2. if a child node is a text node, copy the text to the output
3. if a child node is an element node, start at 1.
4. any other node will be skipped

Your stylesheet only contains a single template matching a single type of node, overriding the default behavior for this type of node.

It contains nothing that would prevent the default rules from running, so you get all kinds of text nodes as part of the output.

Change your stylesheet like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry[1]/wd:Employee_ID" />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- <xsl:template match="props['xpath_matchHoursDateType']">  -->
    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry[1]/wd:Employee_ID">
        <Root>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </Root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and it will start to work the way you expect.

The `template match="/"` will override default behavior directly at the root node and leave no room for the default rules to kick in.

Comment: OOOOOH!!!! That makes sense... This is exactly what I needed to know, thanks!

Comment: You can verify this by supplying an empty stylesheet. It will produce a concatenation of all the text nodes in the document (except the non-relevant whitespace-only nodes "between tags", when `<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />` is set).

Comment: This also explains a lot of other "odd behavior" I've seen with my transforms before. This will make my life a lot easier.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to override the default behavior completely. You can use it to your advantage, because it already implements the recursion for you, but you have to be aware of these rules for that. When done right, all you need to do is implement templates for the nodes you want to process.

Comment: Also, since in this case you are doing a "push style" template (you push the nodes that you want to be processed), combining a specific `<xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry[1]/wd:Employee_ID" />` and a generic `<xsl:template match="wd:Employee_ID">` makes more sense.

Comment: Also, I would pull up the `<Root>`/`</Root>` into the `<xsl:template match="/">`, and you could use `<xsl:copy-of select="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry[1]/wd:Employee_ID" />` instead of the `<xsl:apply-templates ...>`, when copying the nodes is your goal.

Comment: Yeah, I've always suspected that I was missing out on a lot of the template functionality (the work I do is basic enough an rare enough that it hasn't mattered before), and this is clarifying a lot.